# why my navigation cannot generate classes with the suffix Args

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have add

```
 def nav_version = "2.3.3"
 classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
```

to build.gradle of my project .

And

I have add

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
```

to build.gradle of app or module

In dependencies  I also add

```
 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.3',
 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.3',
 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.3',
 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.3'
```

In my graph

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/password_card"
    tools:layout="@layout/layout_refresh_view"
    android:name="com.example.module_password.ui.PasswordCardFragment"
    android:label="@string/card" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/card_to_card_edit"
        app:destination="@id/password_card_edit" >
        <argument

            android:name="isAdd"
            app:argType="boolean"

            android:defaultValue="false"/>
    </action>
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/password_card_edit"
    tools:layout="@layout/password_edit_card"
    android:name="com.example.module_password.ui.PasswordEditCardFragment"
    android:label="" />
```

Finally,the android studio only generate classes with the suffix **Directions**,without classes with the suffix **Args**

Just **PasswordCardFragmentDirections**, without **PasswordEditCardFragmentArgs**

What happen?

Comment: show your navGraph

Comment: OK, thank you for your reminding. I've already added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `argument` tag is misplaced. It should be:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/password_card"
    tools:layout="@layout/layout_refresh_view"
    android:name="com.example.module_password.ui.PasswordCardFragment"
    android:label="@string/card" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/card_to_card_edit"
        app:destination="@id/password_card_edit" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/password_card_edit"
    tools:layout="@layout/password_edit_card"
    android:name="com.example.module_password.ui.PasswordEditCardFragment"
    android:label="">
    <argument
        android:name="isAdd"
        app:argType="boolean"
        android:defaultValue="false" />
</fragment>
```

Comment: Almost at the same time, I also found the answer, thank you!!!!